# смена расположений блоков js, vanilla

Tags: javascript

есть два абзаца, условно A и B, только при нажатии на верхний блок, на сам абзац он меняется местами с нижним, то есть кликабельный только верхний. всегда верхний

Comment: Тут где-то должен быть вопрос? Или к чему это непонятное описание двух абзацев?

Comment: как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

Немного  минимализма :D

```js
document.querySelector('section').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  this !== e.target && this.appendChild(e.target)
})
```

```html
<section>
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
</section>
```